Is there a built-in bibliography style that does *not* change the capitalization?
I expect the answer will be that it simply does not exist, in which case it might be interesting to know why.
At the risk of being too verbose, I'll try to preempt some answers that are not what I'm asking. I understand this not a bug, but a feature. I know that you can enclose specific words in curly braces to avoid this from happening. Some recommend enclosing every title in braces, others just the initial letter, and others just the words. There are scripts in python and other languages to modify bib files automatically. I also know I can change my particular *.bst file.
However, having a built-in style would make my document more portable while avoiding the need check manually or run a script repeatedly.

What do you mean 'built in' - there are many BibTeX styles, most following the requirements of specific journals or publishers

BTW, you should be marking terms which have fixed capitalisation up as a matter of course: this is precisely because it keeps them portable

I actually found the answer to 'built in' styles after more searching. It looks like there is a handful of styles that come prepackaged with LaTeX (see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibtex_bibliography_styles).
As you can see, all these change the case of the title. Why isn't there a built-in option that does not do this?
As for the use case, I am writing an internal report and I don't have to stick a particular style, as long as I am consistent. Given this freedom, I'd like to simply use a bib style that does not change the title case, and I can simply send a bib and tex files.

Those styles aren't really 'built-in' - BibTeX itself comes with a few such as unsrt written when BiBTeX was written, the rest were written to match publisher requirements. A long-standing tradition in publishing in English at least is that there are 'rules' for how to present titles, hence the case changing. Hence saying that your database should be marked up correctly: something like a company name should be {Foo} not Foo in the database to prevent case changing/

You are likely to get on better using biblatex than classical BibTeX as you can make style changing 'in' the document - but again we need some idea of what style you want (there really is no such thing as a 'generic' bibliography style).
